# Play! framework: Change application version in build.sbt is not taken into account

Tags: playframework, sbt, versioning

I would like to change the version of my Play! 2.5 application (running with sbt 0.13.13).
I changed the version in `build.sbt` as following:

```
version := "2"
```

But the version is still the same: if I run `sbt version`, the output is still `0.1-SNAPSHOT`.

Is there an sbt command to run in order to update the version?

Comment: Can we see your `build.sbt`?  If you have multiple projects in your build that might be the culprit.

Comment: You will have to reload your sbt after changing `build.sbt`.

Comment: @josephpconley I indee have multiple projects in my build (a client and shared projects as I use scalaJs).

Comment: @Reactormonk I have reloaded sbt but without effect

Comment: Do you also have a `build.scala`? I think `build.sbt` overrides `build.scala` but might be worth checking.

Comment: @Nio No, I don't have a `build.scala` and yes I have a `project/plugins.sbt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. The problem was that I had multiple project in my build.sbt (thanks to josephpconley to have pointed that).

I defined in build.sbt:

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(version := "0.1")
```

And I defined each project in `build.sbt`, as following:

```
(project in file("server"))
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
  .settings(...
```